# How do I breakdown a PSD Background To Tileable layered elements

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, png, css, mask

I'd like to create a scaleable multi-resolution web effect similar to iBooks and started by building on [this tutorial](http://naldzgraphics.net/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ibook/).

The problem is with the background image:
[image: background image]

As you can see it has two masks on it that give it that special effect:

[image: Masks and layer]

What I want to do is create a background that will fit any resolution, for this I need a tileable version of the image background and a translucent PNG mask image which I can scale on top of that tileable image to give a similar effect.

I have no idea how to convert the mask layers above into a simple raster that I can save as a standalone PNG file. I tried replicating the look using a translucent radial gradient but didn't get anywhere.

Without the mask the image looks like this which is allot less compelling:

[image]

Any tips on how to easily make a texture tileable will also be appreciated but I can probably manage this myself. Thanks.

Comment: It depends a little in how you're thinking about doing it all, but I would basically duplicate that current wooden texture ( Duplicate so that you can see the neutral texture behind it. ) brush a hole in the middle much like in your masks there and maybe raise the saturation a bit, make the color more reddish and make it darker.

Comment: By the way. I could be wrong, but doesn't the question title ask about how to tile up this wooden texture, but in the actual question you ask how to make those vignette's into transcluent png?

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming (and I may be wrong here) that I can get a PNG mask image that will include the effect only (a transparent image) that I can just overlay on the last image within my question to create the first image within my question. This can work well because then I can tile the background image and scale the mask image. If I have a hole in the middle of an image you will see a seam that wouldn't fit.

Comment: Yes. The tiling and the layering are one and the same in my mind, I can't tile the image as it is and if I scale it as it is there will be visible distortion. However, if I can separate it to two layers I can tile the background and scale the overlay layer producing a great effect for all resolutions.

Comment: Here's a quick example of what I'm talking about... http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fztsV/ ( Clicking the container will animate the dimensions. ) What I did was make a crappy pattern from the texture and then crop an area to use as the vignette and then did as I suggested before. The only problem with what I'm suggesting is possible blurring of the texture in the vignette image if it's dimensions become too high, but it should stil work.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what I have been thinking. What you should do actually is to remove those layer masks ( so that you have darker color all around ) and and then merge all of the layers and just brush a hole in the middle ( or possibly use one of the layer masks you've already made to make that hole. ) save that as png and you're done.

Comment: An image with a hole in the center can't be tiled... I need the LIGHTER image to tile (which should be easy) and I need an overlay on top of the tile which I can scale. If the overlay has too much opacity in it, the scaling will break into the tiling of the images.

Comment: And in my example, what is wrong/different from what you want/need?

Comment: The image I have would be lighter not darker. The masks I have are MASK objects which I can't convert to an actual layer. If I flatten them they will merge with the image producing an opaque image. If I make a hole in the image (to show the lighter colored center) there will be a seam between the image within the hole and the image above.

Comment: You need to make a darker image to make that vignette. Those Curve adjustment layers that you have, just shift click those layer masks in them or delete the layer masks and then select all the layers ( at least the ones I'm seeing in your example image ) and merge those layers (Ctrl+E) which leaves you with a darker version of that wooden texture. So, is there something you need to do differently than in my example jsfiddle? ..and I have no idea what seam you are talking about.. I mean.. dark parts do look darker than the light parts, but that is what you are trying to accomplish here, right?

Comment: You are forgetting the TILLING! When I place two of these one next to the other they won't look like a single large board but like two boards with two spots... I want ONE board so the background is tiled but the foreground tints the background. The seam will appear when I have two layers one on top of the other that replicate some of the same pixels. Try doing this not with one image, with two (one next to the other) and you will see what I mean.

Comment: So, again, is there something wrong with my example jsfiddle? Here is the link again http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fztsV/

Comment: It doesn't quite look like the image above and if it was darker you would see that the vertical lines from the surrounding image with the hole start and then end abruptly when hitting the image tiled in the back. Thanks for the effort. Please submit this as an answer if I won't get the answer I want I'll accept this. Sorry if I was a bit vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not feeling very motivated to answer as it seems like you didn't even try my suggestion and you were saying that my idea doesn't work because this and that which just seemed to me like you didn't read my messages properly. ( could be that I wasn't very clear in what I said, but still. )

My example didn't quite look like your image because, I'm not doing your 'work' for you, I'm just suggesting a method for you to do it.

---

Basic idea is this:

1. make a tiling texture.
2. make a non-tiling texture that is based on the prior one so that it is as consistant as possible and make it darker. ( The size
   of this one should be about the *regular* size that the box would
   be. )
3. make a hole in the middle of the non-tiling texture.

If you're super worried about the texture'es having a seam of some sort, you could try to  change it's opacity really low and then darken the non-tiling image even more.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fztsV/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fztsV/1/show/

Clicking the image will show the way non-tiling image looks when the size of it is bigger than the original size of the image.

if you need to allow the size to get quite big, the non-tiling image will get blurry, but you might be able to avoid that by making the non-tiling image a bit bigger than the regular size. ( but then again, little blurring in the edges is not so bad.. )

[image] [image]

---

Note that there is also a way to make this so that  the vignette edges wont scale according the container, but that's even more coding related so I won't go into that.